# How to increase the amount of probing points for a BLTouch sensor in Marlin firmware?

Tags: marlin, bed-leveling, z-probe, bltouch

I have a new BLTouch that is setup (using Marlin 1.8.7) but I want to increase the probing grid from a 3x3 to something like a 5x5. I am using bilinear leveling with a 3x3 grid.

How would I go about changing that?

Answer (score 12):

You need to change the constant value(s) in your [Configuration.h](https://github.com/MarlinFirmware/Marlin/blob/1.1.x/Marlin/Configuration.h) file of your Marlin version from:

```
// Set the number of grid points per dimension.
  #define GRID_MAX_POINTS_X 3
  #define GRID_MAX_POINTS_Y GRID_MAX_POINTS_X
```

to:

```
// Set the number of grid points per dimension.
  #define GRID_MAX_POINTS_X 5
  #define GRID_MAX_POINTS_Y GRID_MAX_POINTS_X
```

This shows that to go from a 3x3 grid to a 5x5 grid you only need to change one value. Do note that you can set `GRID_MAX_POINTS_Y` to any value other than `GRID_MAX_POINTS_X`; replacing `GRID_MAX_POINTS_X` in the line with `GRID_MAX_POINTS_Y` to 4 would yield a 5x4 probe grid:

```
// Set the number of grid points per dimension.
  #define GRID_MAX_POINTS_X 5
  #define GRID_MAX_POINTS_Y 4
```

Comment: "You need to change the constant value(s) in your Configuration.h file of your Marlin version" And, how does one do that?

Comment: @WeldonThomson Download the firmware, get or configure it for your printer, compile the software and install this onto the printer controller board.